# Pythom. pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Можно ли как-то без хендлера считать следующее сообщени епользователя?
Т.е. бот посылает сообщение, и без хендлера ждет когда прийдет что-то от юзера и сразу это использует.

Я понимаю как это со стороны звучит, но я просто обмазался хендлерами, и вот ищу вариант, можно как-то это сократить.

Comment: Зачем ими обмазываться? достаточно одного @bot_handler'a в коде. По крайней мере у меня работало именно так

Comment: @CLL0X00, - bot_handler - один в коде, это я писал про случаи когда нужно считать ответ пользователя с клавиатуры.
Допустим для одного метода, мне нужна почта, для другого телефон и т.д. Это все я хочу в разных методах использовать, поэтому пользуюсь  bot.register_next_step_handler() - вот это мне не нравится что я на каждый пук с чата делаю нового обработчика получается.